# Лично мне не по душе вариант с запятой(,) — мне по душе вариант с двоеточием

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, запятая-перед-тире, запятая-и-тире

Запятая и тире (единый знак) или же просто тире?

`Лично мне не по душе вариант с запятой, — мне по душе вариант с двоеточием.`

Никаких просто запятой! Тире обязательно!

Comment: Кто минусонул? Зачем?

Comment: Да, хотелось узнать причину: чем не понравился вопрос?  Пожалуйста, расскажите нам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NEW! Единый знак. Совмещение значений и знаков: присоединение и сопоставление, запятая и тире.**

**Решение**

Нужно поставить **единый знак:**

*Лично мне не по душе вариант с запятой, — **мне по душе** вариант с двоеточием.*

**Пояснение**

1. **Содержание** высказывания можно обозначить так: *Лично мне по душе вариант **с двоеточием, а не с запятой.*** Здесь однородные дополнения связаны **сопоставительным** союзом А. В БСП **при отсутствии союза А** ставится тире, например: *Служить бы рад — прислуживаться тошно* (Гр.);
   Таким образом, **сопоставительные** отношения при бессоюзной связи мы обозначаем **тире**.
2. Если в заданном предложении поставить **запятую**, то это будет просто **распространение/присоединение**, нам же нужно обозначить и **сопоставительные** отношения тоже.
3. Это можно сделать с помощью **дополнительного** тире, Другими словами, это будет **единый знак.**
   Ни запятая, ни тире **не могут по отдельности** передать нужное значение.
4. **Интонация подходящая**: понижение тона, как при запятой, и большая пауза по сравнению с тире.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Почему так много внимания **к этому предложению?** Оно далеко не всем приглянулось, **что в нем такого?**

Дело не в конкретном предложении, а в его **грамматической модели.** Две части предложения по семантике **сопоставлены**, но интонационного сопоставления **нет.**

Эта модель может применяться с различным **лексическим** наполнением.